# LINQ Like Clause - Without Wildcard operator

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I would like to write a LINQ to SQL query with a Like operator, but without the WildCard operator on it.

I know the following:

Contains will be equivelent to this: a like '%b%'
StartsWith will be equivlent to this: a like 'b%' and EndsWith will be vice versa.

Equals could do it, but "This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison."

The way I am doing now is like this:

```
var  loc  = (from l in data.Locations.OrderBy(l => l.LocationName)
    join s in data.LocationSecurities.Where(s=> s.UserName.ToLower().Equals(userName.ToLower())) on l.LocationID equals s.LocationId
    select new
    {
        LocationId = l.LocationID,
        Name = l.LocationName
    }
    ).Distinct().ToList();
```

But this is only a work-around, because what I want to do is to simply use an equivelent of Like but whitout the WildCard, which get visibly clear on the SQL Server Profiler.

Please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SqlMethods.Like
```

Like:

```
.Where(s => SqlMethods.Like(s.UserName, userName))
```

Comment: The method SqlMethods.Like is not recognized by the compiler; even though this is supposed to be Linq to SQL. @Dave Bish

Comment: @t_plusplus - What? Add a reference to System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods

Answer (score 0):

That `Equals` performs an *"ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison"* does not apply when used with Linq to SQL or Entity framework since the statement will be translated into SQL. 
The database [collation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx#Collation_Defn) (or column collation if set) will determine how `"="` (Equals) is handled.